# SOAP API parameter best practice

Tags: web-services, api, soap, parameters

I have a set of soap webservices that are tightly coupled to an application within the same architecture but I need it to also be an API for other applications to hook into.

At the moment, the services use a parameter (and method) structure like this

**Entity GetEntity(int entityId)
Entity GetEntityByName(string entityName)**
.... etc.

In the case of creates I use:
**void CreateEntity(Entity entity)**

I am wondering though would it be better to do it like this:

**EntityResponse GetEntity(EntityRequest requestObj)** .....

and in the requestObj I have id, entityName and depending what the user supplies, I can perform either function.

and for the create it would be:

**CreateEntityResponse CreateEntity(CreateEntityRequest requestObj).**

My thinking is that by doing it like this, the API can change internally...add new parameters etc without immediately breaking any integration that has already been done.

Comment: Doesnt the Entity object already have all of those properties? If not, why?

Comment: I do have an Entity object and it has everything in it.

I thought about using that too as a parameter but what if I wanted to add another parameter in the future? 

Should I even be factoring that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several design principles that you may want to consider:

1) Database Entity vs Data Transport Object DTO

Looks like those Entities come directly from a database mapping? Just exposing your Entities as API, is basically a fancy SQL Query browser. It's not necessarily wrong but you will achieve better de-coupling if you would expose DTO's in the API.
The DTO's could be more future proof then the Entities and more generic.

2) SOAP vs REST

If you want to achieve a maximum of future proofing you might want to consider REST. With the REST specification you have more options to extend the API later.
For instance if you look at APIs like Facebook they purely pass in parameters and then you receive in return a key-value map of the parameters you passed in. So very generic.
In SOAP you would always end up in defining all of those eventual attributes upfront. You basically need to introduce placeholders et cetera.
There is certainly a reason why SOAP is a good contract protocol and has advantages like code generating tools are more up to date and lots more. But with REST you could be even more flexible while loosing some of the goodies you had in SOAP.

This is also a very good read:
https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/whitepaper/api/secrets-great-api
or generally the RAML design spec from Mule is a very powerful tool when it comes to designing REST APIs.

Comment: Yes, the objects that I have at the moment contain everything from the database. I think I agree that DTO is what I should do but my question is should I wrap them in a request/response object?

Comment: I have seen such constructs before, however I don't see a difference. To me it looks like that same: If you have a "RequestObject" and then put a DTO inside, then your RequestObject is also a DTO! I would only use the RquestObject construct if you have additional MetaInformation that is the same across all remote calls. For instance: UserId, sessionId or similar. So like abstract information independent of the API method. But if it is just functional data, I would put it into the DTO.

Comment: Thanks Seba. I have seen and used that idea in some APIs but not many so was wondering if there was a design principle I might be missing. I will utilize DTO